# Is it possible to create SharePoint workflow tasks in multiple lists?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

I am authoring a SharePoint 2013 workflow. This workflow needs to create tasks. In the workflow setting we can select Task and History list. And when tasks are assigned, task items are created on the task list.

I have a requirement that I have to create task on multiple lists based on certain condition

**Example:**

WF Stage : *Escalate* 
WF Stage : *Exception*

Both the workflow stages will create tasks. 

Tasks created in the "***Escalate***" stage will go to a list called "***Escalate Tasks***" and 
tasks created in the "***Exception***" stage will go to a list called "***Exception Tasks***".

I am able to create tasks on multiple content types of the same list, but cannot find any option to create on multiple lists.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. 
It is a SharePoint limitation, each Workflow is associated with one Task list and one History list but we can overcome this by creating 2010 workflow and call that in 2013 workflow.
SharePoint designer workflow 2013 allows you to call 2010 site workflows or List workflows.

So, you can create two 2010 workflows and associate the respective task lists in that workflow and create tasks using that.

 In your case: 

In WF Stage:Escalate - Call a 2010 workflow which will create task in "Escalate Tasks" list.

In WF Stage:Exception - Call a 2010 workflow which will create task in "Exception Tasks" list.

 Hope this is useful.

Comment: yes. We can do that using secondary workflows. But I am further using the task outcomes. If I create task using another workflow, how can use the outcomes in my primary workflow?

Comment: Assign the outcome to one of the variable. Access the variable in your primary workflow. 2010 workflow variables will be available under datasource - "SharePoint 2010 Output: <Your Workflow Name>"

Comment: 1. Refresh the SharePoint designer 
2. Re-Publish the 2010 workflow  
3. Close and re-open SharePoint designer.

Comment: Do you have a working demo of how to create and use task outcomes ( 2010 )?

Comment: Nope, but I have implemented similar workflows many times. We started using 2010 workflow like subroutines in 2013 to achieve functionalities that are not feasible in 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. 
You can use SharePoint Designer to create the workflow and create new items to any(or multiple) lists.

Regards

Comment: Well. We can always create items in any list. That's true. But is it the case while assigning tasks? I want it to be using "Assign Task" action. When a task is assigned, the workflow automatically creates a task item in the task list. In my scenario, I am trying not using the "Create item" action, but assigning tasks.